# WP7: ListBox Style in DataTemplate throwing parser error

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a Style which looks like this:

```
<Style x:Name="SomeListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <!-- Rest of template is commented out - error still occurs. -->
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And a ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="SomeListBox" Grid.Row="0" SelectionMode="Single" Style="{StaticResource SomeListBoxStyle}" Visibility="Collapsed" SelectionChanged="SomeListBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Upon running, I get the (very helpful) error:

> AG_E_UNKNOWN_ERROR [Line: 22 Position: 211]

This error points to the last attribute of the ListBox (no matter what the last attribute is). How am I applying this DataTemplate incorrectly?

Comment: Can you show the rest of the template - where the ... is.

Comment: I've actually commented and removed the rest of the template so what you see here is what's causing the error. Thanks.

Comment: What about `DefaultListBoxItemStyle`? Are you sure that isn't the culprit?

Comment: Sorry, I've also removed that from the test case - same error with or without that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing Property="Template" to Property="ItemTemplate"

Comment: Ugh! I hate it when I typo like that - so obvious now. Thanks, that was it!